# Parsing JSON data with Volley library

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-volley

i want to parse data from my local created database using android app.i have tried to do it with volley library.It doesn't work..Here is my java code

```
package com.example.hakobm.volleyparsing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/people",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("people");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject people = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String gender = people.getString("gender");
                                String name = people.getString("name");
                                String age = people.getString("age");
                                textview.append(age + " " + name + " " + gender + "\n");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                    }
                }
        );

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

In my opinioin something wrong with this line  "http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/people"

Thanks!

Comment: That link is i think local link.
better copy paste json in pastebin and share that link here.

Comment: What do you mean by `It doesn't work.` ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: i didn't get any error, just i don't see my database

Comment: "http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/people" is this ur database url ?

Comment: yes , instead of localhost i write 10.0.2.2

Comment: it would be better if you just attach JSON this url returns

Answer (score 2):

Use JSONObjectRequest to parsing json from volley,

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {
                        // Parsing json object response
                        // response will be a json object
                        String name = response.getString("name");
                        String email = response.getString("email");
                        JSONObject phone = response.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");

                        jsonResponse = "";
                        jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n";

                        txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // hide the progress dialog
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            });
```